# Mostrar datos de un api en una tabla

Tags: vue.js, api

Hola buenos días primeramente

estoy tratando de mostrar unos datos de una API que estoy consumiendo con VueJS, pero a la hora de mostrarlos me sale el campo en blanco  asi

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esta seria la parte donde estoy consumiendo la API

```js
<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return{
            info: [],
        }
    },
    created(){
        this.mostrarcompra();
        
    },
    methods: {
        mostrarcompra(){
            this.axios.get('/tracings')
            .then( res => {
                console.log(res.data);
                this.info = res.data;
            })
            .catch(e => {
                console.log(e.response);
            })

        }
    }
}
</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```

y efectivamente me trae los datos de la API
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y aqui esta la tabla donde quiero comprar los datos, y lo tengo con su respectivo v-for para que me recorra info para mostrarlo, pero igual me sale en blanco

```js
 <template>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>pruebas</h1>
        <table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>request_code</th>
      <th scope="col">need</th>
      <th scope="col">status</th>
      <th scope="col">Fecha</th>
      <th scope="col">Acciones</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr v-for="(item, index) in info" :key="index">
      <th scope="row">{{item.request_code}}</th>

      
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
    </div>
</template>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```

lo que me aparece en consola[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

espero que puedan ayudarme, y que tengan un feliz dia

Comment: Por favor tu código como texto

Comment: ok perfecto ya lo hare

Comment: listo ya puse el código como texto

Comment: no uses created, usa mounted.. mira el ciclo de vida encreate no hace nada

Comment: ya lo cambie, pero igual me parece la tabla sin el dato que le estoy pidiendo

Comment: La consola te muestra algun error?

Comment: no ningún error, me trae la API, pero cuando quiero mostarla en la tabla no me muestra el dato

Comment: Ocupamos la URL para poder replicar tu ejercicio

Comment: fijate en la consola de vue el objeto luego de hacer la consulta tiene algun valor...

Comment: la url es esta es por un puerto http://localhost:3000/tracings estoy haciendo el back con typeorm @BetaM

Comment: @gbianchi♦ me aparece esto {status: 200, message: Array(2)}

Comment: eso es lo que viene en tu data y tenes dentro de info? me parece que estas entendiendo mal que devuelve tu api.. o nos estas diciendo otra cosa.. y por eso no ves nada en tu pantalla... porque no hay lo que vos pensas que hay...

Comment: @gbianchi♦ amigo hay alguna otra forma de contactarte para enviarte la imagen de lo que me aparece en mi consola cuando consumo la API?

Comment: subi la imagen a la pregunta. a mi no me queda claro que tu variable tenga lo que vos decis, despues de obtener el valor de la api...

Comment: gbianchi♦ listo amigo ya la acabo de subir

Comment: y la variable info que tiene? fijate en la consola de vue...

Comment: parece que la api te está devolviendo un solo objeto y no un array de objetos. puede ser? prueba imprimir directamente la propiedad del objeto en vez de hacer un v-for `<th scope="row">{{info.request_code}}</th>`